# Assignment a value to Events

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417992/c-sharp-events-with-custom-event-accessor-add-and-remove) and while I think I mostly understand event accessors two other aspects of this confused me.

First:

`private event Action<int> ActivityChanged = delegate {};`

Was this event assigned a value with [variable-initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#variable-initializers), my understanding was that only += and -= operators were permmited on events? What does the anonymous method do here?

Second:

```
event Action<int> IActivityFacade.ActivityChanged
{
    add
    {
        ActivityChanged += value;
        value(GetSelectedActivity()); 
    }
    remove { ActivityChanged -= value; }
}
```

Was the first line a forward declaration and the second a definition? I come from a C++/C background and that is what this appeared to me but for all I know it could mean something else entirely. Are forward declarations even allowed in C#

Comment: additionally, from the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors) the variable name IDrawingObject.OnDraw has a member access in it? Is this also forward declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first line is private member and actual 'event' with dummy initializer. event have operators += and -= for subscribe and unsubscribe, without dummy it throws null reference
- second is a publicly available accessor for subscribers with same += and -=

with member event you can fire them as follow this.ActivityChanged() [some example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events)

IActivityFacade.ActivityChanged this mean class implements interface and we explicitly define it as event accessor about [interface events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-interface-events) and [explicit enterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)